# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have this error in the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount()' on a null object reference
```

when i try to do a for loop on the adapter. I think that it crashes because the adapter is declared in an activity but the cycle that i need to do is in another one. Infact in the activity in which i'm doing the loop i have write this so far:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
               String fermata_partenza = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PreferitiDb.KEY_FERMATA_PARTENZA));
               String fermata_arrivo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PreferitiDb.KEY_FERMATA_ARRIVO));
               Log.i("",fermata_partenza + " " + fermata_arrivo);


               for (int i = 0; i < SceltaFermateActivity.instance.adapter.getCount(); i++){
                   FermataComune obj = SceltaFermateActivity.instance.adapter.getItem(i);

                   if (obj.toString().contains(fermata_partenza)){
                       feramta_Partenze = (FermataComune) obj;
                   }
                   if (obj.toString().contains(fermata_arrivo)){
                       fermata_Arrivi = (FermataComune) obj;
                   }
               }

            }
        });
```

and the error is in line: `SceltaFermateActivity.instance.adapter.getCount();`
is it possible solve?

Comment: Show us where the static `SceltaFermateActivity.instance` field is set.

Comment: So where is the adapter for this `listView` ?

Comment: Static variables are never a good idea.

Comment: This is `SceltaFermateActivity.instance.adapter.getCount()` null.

Comment: It is not the problem of the adapter of the listview. It's the adapter of a spinner in the other activity. I really don't know how solve.. I know that SceltaFermateActivity.instance.adapter.getCount() is null.. but i suppose that is null because in in another class. But i need check this adapter and make the count... Is there another way maybe?